# get data by id from mongoDb atlas data collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to get data by using id but I always get `500` internal error. It would be great help if someone help to find what error I have done to `get` request. I have done post request successfully and stored data to `MyDatabase` collection of MongoDb Atlas

Here is my code:

```
app.get("/student/:id", function (req, res) {
  db.collection("MyDatabase").findOne(req.params.id, function (err, docs) {
    if (err) {
      handleError(res, err.message, "Failed to get student record.");
    } else {
      res.status(200).json(docs);
    }
  });
});
```

I have tried :

```
var ObjectId = require("mongodb").ObjectID;
  db.collection("MyDatabase").findOne(
    { _id: new ObjectId(id) }
```

but still not working

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @JatinParate  error is `500 internal Server Error`

Comment: According to documentation, i didn't find findById method on collection instance, refer this: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html

Use findAndModify instead or create a model

Comment: @JatinParate I tried using `findOne` according to the documentation and still I'm getting same error. I have updated my posted code.

Comment: It's not `findOne(req.params.id)`
It's `findOne({ _id: req.params.id })`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me :

```
app.get("/student/:id", function (req, res) {
  const id = req.params.id;
  var o_id = new mongoDB.ObjectID(id);
  db.collection("MyDatabase").findOne({ _id: o_id }, function (err, docs) {
    if (err) {
      handleError(res, err.message, "Failed to get student data.");
    } else {
      res.status(200).json(docs);
    }
  });
});
```